# App Size and dynamically downloading resources

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My application that will be posted soon is going to dynamically download images and resources that have to do with art when something is unlocked in the app. This will keep down on app size and the app will only download resources when it is needed. Very similarly to Droid development since they cap at 50mb sizes.

Does anyone know if this could potentially harm the approval process to apple? The expansions that will be downloaded could be around 30mb and could be very slow if the user decides to do this on data. Any advice or prior issues with apple on some type of process like this would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should be good.** I have an app that downloads every new XKCD webcomic when it is released.  Each being an image, this has added considerable size to the app.

To play it safe, I would suggest including something in the app description (within the app and on the iTunes store) that tells users the app dynamically downloads content.  There is no rule against it, but letting the user know is always good.